# how to specify in a makefile where to send the results too

Tags: linux, svn, makefile, latex

Right now I have a makefile that build the .tex file (latex) in the same directory as it and spits out a pdf version of that file and also a bunch of baggage with it. I was wondering how to specify in the make file where to send the result. I want to send the results to my desktop directory. Is this at all possible? Also I used the clean function to get rid of the auto-generated garbage files but it still spits them out. any help on that?

```
  PDFLATEX=/usr/texbin/pdflatex
SOURCE=report_Template.tex
RESULT=report_Template.pdf

$(RESULT): $(SOURCE)
        $(PDFLATEX) $(SOURCE)
        $(PDFLATEX) $(SOURCE)

clean:
        rm -f $(RESULT) *.aux *.log *.toc *.out *~
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something make has anything to do with. The commands you run put their output where you tell them to.

It appears that `pdflatex` creates the output next to the input so in whatever directory you run it (and the makefile) from.

You can add a `cp` to the end of that rule to copy the file wherever you want and/or see if `pdflatex` has an argument that can be given for output filename.

That being said if your make target rule doesn't create the target filename exactly that's a poor rule and might cause you trouble in larger make setups. (This is what `.PHONY` rules are for in part.)

`clean` is not magic. It is simply a target like any other. You need to run it for it to do anything.